# Как сделать кривую стрелку html css js

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать такую стрелку, подскажите пожалуйста

Comment: В SVG сделайте. В чистом виде на CSS – это почти невозможно, или будет то ещё извращение

Comment: Попробуйте сделать кривую Безье на канвасе.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно на CSS..

```css
.title {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  padding-right: 120px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 150%;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

.title > span {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}

.curve-arrow {  
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  border-radius: 0 40% 75% 0 / 0 40% 60% 0;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  border-left-color: transparent;
  position: absolute;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  top: calc(1.5em / 2);
  right: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}


/* "обрезаем" верхний хвостик (начало) */
.curve-arrow::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 50%;
  height: 2px;
  background: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  left: -2px;
  top: -2px;
}

/* стрелочка (конец) */

.curve-arrow::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 15px;
  height: 20px;
  background-image:
    linear-gradient(-45deg, transparent calc(50% - 1.15px), #000 calc(50% - .75px), #000 calc(50% + .75px), transparent calc(50% + 1.15px)),
    linear-gradient(45deg, transparent calc(50% - 1.15px), #000 calc(50% - .75px), #000 calc(50% + .75px), transparent calc(50% + 1.15px));
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 0 0, 0 100%;
  background-size: auto 50%;
  position: absolute;
  left: -3px;
  bottom: -11px;
}
```

```html
<div class="title"><span>В ПОДАРОК</span> <div class="curve-arrow"></div></div>
```

Но лучше SVG.

```css
.title {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  padding-right: 120px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 150%;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

.title .curve-arrow {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: calc(1.5em / 2);
}
```

```html
<div class="title">В ПОДАРОК <svg class="curve-arrow" viewbox="-.05 -.05 8 6"><path d="M4 0C8 1 7 4 0 5M0 5 .45 4.5M0 5 .45 5.5" fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-width=".05" stroke-linecap="round"/></svg></div>
```